# Laravel - dont update photo if $request->file('photo') is null

Tags: php, laravel, controller, request, insert-update

Here I have Laravel update function,so with this function I update fields and here is imporant input **PHOTO**

My code is:

```
public function update($id, Requests\ArticleRequest $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'photo' => 'image|max:10000',
            // validate also other fields here
        ]);
        // checking file is valid.
        if (!$request->file('photo')->isValid()) return redirect()->back()->withErrors(["photo" => "File is corrupt"]);

        // file is valid
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/images'; // upload path
        $extension = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
        $filename  = str_random(5).'.'.$extension; // give a name to the image
        $request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $filename); // uploading file to given path
         // sending back with message

        $article = Auth::user()->articles()->findOrFail($id); //if article id is unique just write Article::findOrFail($id)
        $article_fields = $request->except('photo');
        $article_fields['photo'] = $filename;
        $article->update($article_fields);

        Alert::message('Your auction is updated', 'Wonderful!');

        return redirect('auctions');
            }
```

so when I choose some image to update photo everything is fine,but when I want to update other fileds and photo to stay the same at database... I get error:

```
Call to a member function isValid() on a non-object
```

How I can skip photo if $request->file('photo') is blank, so no new image choosen...

Comment: `if (!$request->file('photo')` is enough

Comment: but problem is at the bottom of code: $article_fields['photo'] = $filename; so this will update my photo column... how to skip this ?

Comment: You just skip updating that column if there's no file..

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update($id, Requests\ArticleRequest $request){
        **//check if file provided**
        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {

            $this->validate($request, [
            'photo' => 'image|max:10000',
            // validate also other fields here
        ]);
        // checking file is valid.
         if (!$request->file('photo')->isValid()) return redirect()->back()->withErrors(["photo" => "File is corrupt"]);

        // file is valid
         $destinationPath = public_path().'/images'; // upload path
          $extension = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
          $filename  = str_random(5).'.'.$extension; // give a name to the image
           $request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $filename); // uploading file to given path
         // sending back with message

           $article = Auth::user()->articles()->findOrFail($id); //if article id is unique just write Article::findOrFail($id)
           $article_fields = $request->except('photo');
           $article_fields['photo'] = $filename;
           $article->update($article_fields);

           Alert::message('Your auction is updated', 'Wonderful!');

           return redirect('auctions');
        }
  Alert::message('Nothing to update', 'So sad!'); 
 return redirect('auctions');
}
```